# Linq "Sequence operators not supported for type" Exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write a linq query which populates a dataGridView:

```
dataGridViewNorthWind.DataSource = (from products in dc.Products where 
         products.ProductName.StartsWith("C") && products.ProductName.Contains('a') 
         select new { products.ProductName, products.Category });
```

but I'm getting an "Sequence operators not supported for type string" exception. What`s wrong here?

PS. Any tips on building better queries are welcome, it`s my very first contact with Linq :)

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? Something else? Also, is that the whole message? There seems to be something missing.

Comment: Linq to SQL I think though to be honest I`m not sure. What`s the exact difference between those two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you cant use the Contains method in the way you're hoping. But, you can try this, I changed the argument to the Contains method from a char to a string

```
dataGridViewNorthWind.DataSource = (from products in dc.Products where 
         products.ProductName.StartsWith("C") && products.ProductName.Contains("a") 
         select new { products.ProductName, products.Category });
```